# Programatically create shipment for magento order with tracking - Getting error: Mage_Api_Model_Resource_Abstract->_fault('not_exists')

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I create shipments programatically and try to set a tracking number like this:

```
// ... snipped; code that prepares shipment data ...

// Create Shipment
$shipment = $order->prepareShipment($item_qtys);
$shipment->register();
$shipment->sendEmail(false)
         ->setEmailSent(false)
         ->save();
$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
         ->addObject($shipment)
         ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
         ->save();
$order->save();

// Add Shipment Tracking Number If Available
if (!empty($order_info->TrackingNumber)) {

    var_dump($shipment->getId());
    var_dump($order->getShippingCarrier()->getCarrierCode());
    var_dump($order->getShippingCarrier()->getConfigData('title'));
    var_dump($order_info->TrackingNumber);
    echo "\r\n";

    Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_api')
        ->addTrack(
            $shipment->getId(),
            $order->getShippingCarrier()->getCarrierCode(),
            $order->getShippingCarrier()->getConfigData('title'),
            $order_info->TrackingNumber
        );
}
```

When the above code executes, I get the following output & exception:

```
string(7) "1598070"
string(13) "productmatrix"
string(15) "Shipping Option"
string(14) "TEST1234567890"

not_exists - Stack Trace: #0 /var/www/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Shipment/Api.php(187): Mage_Api_Model_Resource_Abstract->_fault('not_exists')
#1 /var/www/public_html/app/code/community/Mycompanyname/Mymodulename/controllers/Mymodulename/ApiController.php(1266): Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api->addTrack('1598070', 'productmatrix', 'Shipping Option', 'TEST1234567890')
#2 /var/www/public_html/app/code/community/Mycompanyname/Mymodulename/controllers/Mymodulename/ApiController.php(82): Mycompanyname_Mymodulename_Mymodulename_ApiController->NewOrderShipment('{"MagentoOrderI...')
#3 /var/www/public_html/app/code/community/Mycompanyname/Mymodulename/controllers/Mymodulename/ApiController.php(66): Mycompanyname_Mymodulename_Mymodulename_ApiController->Handle_Request('NewOrderShipmen...', '{"MagentoOrderI...')
#4 /var/www/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(421): Mycompanyname_Mymodulename_Mymodulename_ApiController->v2Action()
#5 /var/www/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('v2')
#6 /var/www/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#7 /var/www/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#8 /var/www/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#9 /var/www/public_html/index.php(103): Mage::run('default', 'store')
#10 {main}
```

Any idea what's causing the error? Is this the incorrect way to add tracking number?

Is it possible to set tracking number as you are creating the shipment?

---

I've also tried to achieve this using a different method like this:

```
// If order can be shipped
if ($order->canShip())
{
    // Create shipment
    $shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment($item_qtys);
    $shipment = new Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api();
    $shipmentId = $shipment->create($orderId);

    // If tracking number is available
    if (!empty($order_info->TrackingNumber))
    {
        // Add shipment tracking
        $shipment->addTrack(
            $shipmentId,
            $order->getShippingCarrier()->getCarrierCode(),
            $order->getShippingCarrier()->getConfigData('title'),
            $order_info->TrackingNumber
        );
    }
}
```

This also gives me the following error:

> order_not_exists - Stack Trace: #0
>   /var/www/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Shipment/Api.php(138):
>   Mage_Api_Model_Resource_Abstract->_fault('order_not_exist...')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been trying to solve this via models with so many variation and none of them are working. I am quite tired with this approach, so I have solved it using direct SQL like this:

```
// Add Shipment Tracking Number If Available
if (!empty($order_info->TrackingNumber))
{
    // Get db resources
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
    $shipmentTrackTable = $resource->getTableName('sales_flat_shipment_track');

    // Insert tracking manually
    $writeConnection->query(
        "INSERT INTO `$shipmentTrackTable` (`parent_id`, `order_id`, `track_number`, `title`, `carrier_code`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) 
         VALUES (:parent_id, :order_id, :track_number, :title, 'custom', :created_at, :updated_at)",
        array(
            'parent_id'    => $shipment->getId(),
            'order_id'     => $order->getId(),
            'track_number' => $order_info->TrackingNumber,
            'title'        => 'My Module Name',
            'created_at'   => now(),
            'updated_at'   => now(),
        ));
}
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue (as suggseted by sergio) is when you are trying to call: `$shipmentId = $shipment->create($orderId);`

Here, you're not actually sending through the order ID as your comment suggests, however, looking at `Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Shipment_Api` `create` method, you need to pass through the order `increment_id` rather than `the entity_id` as this is how it loads the order in the first line.

```
/**
 * Create new shipment for order
 *
 * @param string $orderIncrementId
 * @param array $itemsQty
 * @param string $comment
 * @param booleam $email
 * @param boolean $includeComment
 * @return string
 */
public function create($orderIncrementId, $itemsQty = array(), $comment = null, $email = false,
    $includeComment = false
) {
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
```

If you update your code to:
`$shipmentId = $shipment->create($order->getIncrementId());` I'd expect it to find the right order.